# How to calculate Number of Elements of an array using array address?

Tags: c++, c

So I got question in my mind!
How am I suppose to calculate the Number of elements in an array when I have only its address
Suppose I pass  an array "A" as an actual parameter to a function and i stored its address in a pointer suppose "*b".
Now how will I be able to calculate the length of array A(or number of elements in and array A) with its address(base address) only.
Please tell me if I am thinking logically or it.
If it is possible please tell me how
If not please correct me Why!
I can of course calculate length first and the pass both to other functions.

Comment: You can't. Period.

Comment: The address does not carry that information.  You must convey it separately, or else have some mechanism for recognizing the end from the data themselves.  The canonical example of the latter would be C strings.

Comment: Since you have C++ tagged, consider abandoning the use of raw arrays and using a library container like [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) or [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead.

Comment: Roger That Sir!